# Logstash input Cloudwatch logs config

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, amazon-cloudwatch

I am needing to pull in logs from from Cloudwatch to Logstash for my application load balancers. I have multiple that I want to read in for. I was wondering if anyone knew the capabilities behind the `filters` field in the config file.

Basically I am curious if i can put multiple `LoadBalancer` IDs in the `filters` field or if I have to have seperate `input` fields for each one?

```
input {
    cloudwatch {
        namespace => "AWS/ApplicationELB"
        metrics => [my_metrics]
        filters => {"LoadBalancer" => "name1", "LoadBalancer" => "name2"}
        region => "my_region"
    }
}
```

OR

```
input {
    cloudwatch {
        namespace => "AWS/ApplicationELB"
        metrics => [my_metrics]
        filters => {"LoadBalancer" => "name1"}
        region => "my_region"
    }
}

input {
    cloudwatch {
        namespace => "AWS/ApplicationELB"
        metrics => [my_metrics]
        filters => {"LoadBalancer" => "name2"}
        region => "my_region"
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

What you can possibly do is:

- First Create a Log group in CloudWatch , [Follow this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Create-Log-Group.html)

Then you can add [this plugin](https://github.com/lukewaite/logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs/)  to your Logstash and make use of log group you created in cloudwatch.

Hope it will help !